# How to persist this whole page same with adding background color using div tag

Tags: css, html

I had a page which has one background image on that i am keeping some buttons. But the background of the whole page is white. That's not good i want background color and i need to persist this whole thing same.

```
    <html>
    <body>
        <div class="outer" style="background-image:url('BG_BLUE_NEW.jpg'); background-repeat:no-repeat;background-position:center;height:768px;width:1100px;margin-top:-50px:padding-left:0px"></div>
        <div class="login" style="margin-top:-430px;float: left;height: 290px;">
                <form style="padding-left:250px;">
                    <INPUT TYPE="button" style="background-color:SteelBlue;width:100px;height:30px;font-size:150%;margin-bottom:10px" VALUE="Submit" onClick="window.open('http://www.google.com','_blank');"><br>
                    <INPUT TYPE="button" style="background-color:SteelBlue;width:100px;height:30px;font-size:150%;margin-bottom:10px" VALUE="Submit" onClick="window.open('http://www.google.com','_blank');"><br>
                    <INPUT TYPE="button" style="background-color:SteelBlue;width:100px;height:30px;font-size:150%;margin-bottom:10px" VALUE="Submit" onClick="window.open('http://www.google.com','_blank');"><br>
                    <INPUT TYPE="button" style="background-color:SteelBlue;width:100px;height:30px;font-size:150%;margin-bottom:10px" VALUE="Submit" onClick="window.open('http://www.google.com','_blank');"><br>
                    <INPUT TYPE="button" style="background-color:SteelBlue;width:100px;height:30px;font-size:150%;margin-bottom:10px" VALUE="Submit" onClick="window.open('http://www.google.com','_blank');"><br>
                </form>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: 9 questions and no accepted answers? Do you know how to use SO?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this ,
http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_background_shorthand

background-color
background-image
background-repeat
background-attachment
background-position

background:#ffffff url('img_tree.png') no-repeat right top;

```
 <html>
<body>
    <div class="outer" style="background: blue url('BG_BLUE_NEW.jpg') center; height:768px;width:1100px;margin-top:-50px:padding-left:0px"></div>
    <div class="login" style="margin-top:-430px;float: left;height: 290px;">
            <form style="padding-left:250px;">
                <INPUT TYPE="button" style="background-color:SteelBlue;width:100px;height:30px;font-size:150%;margin-bottom:10px" VALUE="Submit" onClick="window.open('http://www.google.com','_blank');"><br>
                <INPUT TYPE="button" style="background-color:SteelBlue;width:100px;height:30px;font-size:150%;margin-bottom:10px" VALUE="Submit" onClick="window.open('http://www.google.com','_blank');"><br>
                <INPUT TYPE="button" style="background-color:SteelBlue;width:100px;height:30px;font-size:150%;margin-bottom:10px" VALUE="Submit" onClick="window.open('http://www.google.com','_blank');"><br>
                <INPUT TYPE="button" style="background-color:SteelBlue;width:100px;height:30px;font-size:150%;margin-bottom:10px" VALUE="Submit" onClick="window.open('http://www.google.com','_blank');"><br>
                <INPUT TYPE="button" style="background-color:SteelBlue;width:100px;height:30px;font-size:150%;margin-bottom:10px" VALUE="Submit" onClick="window.open('http://www.google.com','_blank');"><br>
            </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS:

```
body
{
    background: color: #f00; /*your color here*/
}
```

This will make the body element's background whichever color you choose for all the pages.

Answer (score 0):

```
   body {
      background-color: #ff0000
   }
```